# performance issue of - one to many JPA records

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have relationship with one to many (parent- child ) relationship. while using JPA save method.

Parent have one record child have 5000 to 10000 records .  5k records are in list

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = testId")
private List<test> testList;
```

Likewise I defined . but while I am saving it take much time . how to reduce the save timing .

Comment: Please post your child class code too

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can try (as you need to insert large amount of elements) is to use batch insert. You need to change your application.yml as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true # Just to make sure that your inserts are batched
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 250 # 250 is just an example, feel free to change it as you want
```